# Dell Vostro touchpad gestures not working on Windows 10 -- but do work on any Linux distro

Tags: windows-10, drivers, synaptics-touchpad, dell-vostro

This has been bothering me more than I'd like to admit.

I have a Dell Vostro 3460 (exactly [this one](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/servicetag/2y3c0y1/configuration) to be more specific) running Windows 10 Professional 64-bits, with the latest updates and proper drivers and software installed as far as I am aware of (but probably something is missing since I have this problem).

None of the touchpad gestures listed on the [official Microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027871/windows-10-touchpad-gestures) are working, in fact, I can't even find the options they refer to in my settings page (besides the one to select an item which is the simplest one of all).

The gesture I wish to work is the simple scroll gesture with two fingers. This gesture, in particular, works fine on any Linux distro I have ever installed on this laptop, but Windows 10 doesn't recognize it. Having this gesture enabled would make my life overall 0.0017% easier.

Am I missing something here? Maybe I should be using another touchpad software/driver? Help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you just look for the Touchpad driver name which is currently installed (Can be retrieved from Device Manager) ? might help us in getting the settings/configuration method for the same.

Comment: @NWishAll I've added a screenshot of the device details from the Device Manager.

Comment: are you getting any icon related to the touchpad in the right corner of the taskbar? If yes ,have you tried exploring **Touchpad Properties?** , might sound basic , but just a ground check...as for most of the models ,the gestures is not enabled by default

Comment: No, I have no icon there, and when I search for "touchpad" in the start menu, I can only find Windows 10's own touchpad settings app.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried every possible solutions online, but none of it worked and I have tried new one. I hope this might help you.

I'm Using Dell Inspiron 5558, Windows 10 Home (x64) and i got this problem yesterday.

Before attempting this make sure you have updated all dell drivers and intel drivers successfully.

If you open Device Manager in Control Panel, and under Human Interface Devices -> I2C HID Device is showing "This device cannot start. (Code 10). A request for the HID descriptor failed.", and the touchpad clicks is working but not the gestures, then I got the correct solution that worked for me.

See if there is a file "hidi2c.inf" in "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\hidi2c.inf_amd64_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" (where x is some random id). Right Click and Choose Install.

If it shows Operation completed, you can see that the gestures come working and options to modify in Windows Settings app.

If you can't find the file "hidi2c.inf" then there is no alternative i could suggest to my knowledge right now.